# Navigate to selected Item from Listbox on DblClick (excel)

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I have a Listbox1 with 5 Columns with headers.(Name, Background, Secondary, Keyword and hyperlink.) The listbox displays a filtered search.

At the moment the link is to a Folder path:
strFolderPath = "C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Flags"

I am trying to write it so that the usercan double click an item in the listbox and it navigate to the Hyperlinked name and add it to the path and navigate to it.

So for example the user double click on entry 3 which has "USA" in the hyperlink. Then VB will navigate to "C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Flags\USA.JPG" and open the jpeg for the user.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try something? Your efforts? Any?

Comment: So what is your problem? Don't you know how to check if a user did a double click on an item in the listbox? Or don't you know how to open the JPG via VBA? Or ...

Comment: Storax - I dont know how to open the JPG via VBA

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                       
string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();                                                        int index = listBox2.FindString(curItem);

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution to my problem.
Here is what i have so far.
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Flags\" & Me.ListBox1.Column(4) & ".jpg"

It works fine except that the jpeg opens via internet explorer and not through paint or photos 3d. Also i am limited to .jpg

So the next step is to find out how to open it through photo viewer or pain and also accept any format such as .jpg and other than typing in the file format as part of column(4)

happy if anyone would have an idea or point me in the right direction